Flutter APP/API testing integrated with Java/Serenity Framework
Currently, we have a Serenity BDD/Java framework for our front-end automation. This is for component and E2E tests. However, we also have a Flutter driver framework for our app/api tests. We would like to integrate the two. 
There was an idea to use Appium. However, I wanted to know if anyone managed to find a way to integrate the two frameworks without Appium. I am not sure this is even possible. The reason is that Flutter is much faster, and I've seen a few issues when some were automating Flutter with Appium.

Integrating without Appium
While Appium is a popular option for cross-platform mobile automation, it is possible to integrate Serenity BDD/Java with the Flutter Driver framework without using Appium. This approach can potentially offer better performance and avoid potential issues associated with Appium and Flutter.
Here are two potential approaches for integration:

Using the Flutter Driver API directly:
Pros:
Direct access to the Flutter Driver API for full control over test execution.
Potentially faster and more efficient than using Appium.
Avoids the overhead of Appium and potential compatibility issues.
Cons:
Requires writing Java code to interact with the Flutter Driver API.
May require additional effort to integrate with Serenity BDD/Java reporting and test management tools.
Using a third-party library like flutter_driver_test:
Pros:
Provides a Java API for interacting with the Flutter Driver API.
Simplifies integration with Serenity BDD/Java.
Offers additional features like test reporting and screenshot capture.
Cons:
Introduces an additional dependency.
May not offer the same level of flexibility as directly using the Flutter Driver API.
Additional Considerations:
Test execution environment: Ensure you have the necessary tools and dependencies for running Flutter Driver tests, such as the Flutter SDK and a compatible device or emulator.
Test reporting and management: Choose a suitable reporting tool to integrate with Serenity BDD/Java for test results and logs.
Test maintenance: Consider the long-term maintenance and scalability of your chosen integration approach.

